# PHP PDO - Understanding for beginners

Tags: php, pdo

I've read through [PHP PDO Book](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and now have some basic questions:

1. If i understood correctly, i'll have to use `begin_transaction()` in order to turn off autocommit. If i am okay with autocommit, i am always good to go with a simple `query()`
   Is this correct?
2. Did i get it right, that there is basically no difference between `query()` and `exec()`, except of the above asked topic?
3. I made a query like this one:

   ```
   foreach ($db->query('SELECT * from user') as $row) {
     $row = json_encode($row);
     echo $row;
   }
   ```

Which returns a JSON Object:

```
    {
     "alias":"tk",
     "0":"tk",
     "password":"pw",
     "1":"pw",
    }
```

This is basically correct, however, why is each value returned twice, once with my chosen keyword and another time with an Integer key?

Comment: Set your `fetchmode` as you want it.

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference for the above asked topic?

Comment: @YourCommonSense

guess my sentence construction was misleading, excuse me.   What i wanted to ask, is: Am i right that i can use both methods equally, excpet from the fact that excec() is used for non-autocommit statements only?

Comment: Why do you think excec() is used for non-autocommit statements only?

Comment: @YourCommonSense
Because i found it to be mentioned only together with a previous call of `begin_transaction()`

Comment: 1. Where did you get that? 2. Why don't you test it yourself? 3. what is that begin_transaction() you are talking about? 4. Why don't you want to put your hands on the matter and see everything yourself?

Comment: @YourCommonSense
I appreciate your will to help greatly. If you don't want to answer my actual question, but instead try to give me advice on HOW TO ask, then i understand that.
However, i greatly believe that i showed some effort to understand that by myself.
I could have tested by myself and maybe found out whether or nor it would work. But instead, i wanted to know how this would be done by a professional developer.
Some OT; i have read your profile on meta SO and agree with you in most cases. But at the end of the day, every novice is happy about any information on this overwhelming topic

Comment: To tell you truth, there are no professional developers around. Professional developers has some stuff to develop, you know, and has not much time to hang around. In *reality*, your words *actually* mean "I could have tested [and have certain proof that makes me a professional myself], but I want an answer from [some uncredited people who have no knowledge but only desire for reputation points]". Besides that, the question is too silly for involving a professional. Please check your premises. They are false a big lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is each value returned twice, once with my chosen keyword and another time with an Integer key?

The array has the values both with the **column names** as keys, and **the column ordinals** too. So you could access the values from the result set by using the number of which column you want. (of course, that does not seem to be of too much use with a `select *` statement...)

You can affect this behaviour with [`PDOStatement::setFetchMode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php). The constants starting with `PDO::FETCH_` are applicable here. [Their documentation can be found here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)